# Kendo UI MVC + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with using Kendo UI MVC and AngularJS in my MVC application.

```
<div class="details-container" ng-module="app.branch" ng-controller="GeoController">
@{
    Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Name("BranchTabStrip")
        .HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "tabStrip-no-border-no-padding"})
        .Items(parent =>
        {
            var parameters = new {Id = Model.Id};
            parent.LoadSecureTab("General", "GeneralTab", "GeneralTab", "Branch", parameters);
        })
        .Render();
}</div>
```

This is my html mark up of Kendo UI TabStrip with single tab.

Inside of this tab I'm putting next snippet with angularjs bindings:

```
<p>
    {{branch.Name}}
</p>
```

But in result, in browser I see the next:
[My tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CRDW.png)

If move this snippet to above than kendo tab,

```
{{branch.Name}}
```

in this case, it's will work and diplays my text in Name variable

I think, that Kendo overrides angularjs scope by own scope and in conclusion, angular bindings are not working.

Guys, any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: First of all, you're mixing both the server side rendering and client side data binding for no reason. Either use the server side as a regular asp.net app or use client side binding as Angular "Single Page Application".

Comment: In mvc *.cshtml is mixing too (html+server). 
So in my case, it's normally and server side already is used and now need to apply angularjs with them

Comment: You might need to nest as `<text>{{branch.Name}}</text>` in order to produce a page-basis that angular will pickup on.